# Are there any good books on propositional, first order, and second order logic that don't require me to be a supergenius?

Tags: logic, reference-request, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, second-order-logic

I am trying to learn mathematical logic but every textbook I come across is so hard to read and understand, and assumes I'm already an expert in everything. Is there anything aimed at beginners that is actually quite thorough and does a good job explaining things to someone with no prior exposure?

Comment: To help you find books you might understand, it would help if you listed some of the books you find hard to understand.

Comment: W.V.O. Quine’s “Elementary Logic” starts pretty basic and conversationally — maybe look into that (and it has problems and solutions)

Comment: @GerryMyerson Almost any of them from https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/Appendix.pdf -- even the author's reviews range from "too hard" to "assumes lots of background knowledge already" to "daunting size" to "uneven," etc. I tried Joseph R. Shoenfield’s Mathematical Logic, and Logic and Structure by Van Dalen, and indeed these books were incredibly hard to read and not aimed at beginners. Every resource I check out is overly dense and simultaneously all over the place.

Comment: @Bey That one is a little too simple for me, I know how to interpret and put together formulas without issue

Comment: [van Dalen](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&printsec=frontcover) has also a chapter on SOL.

Comment: @DanChristensen: the link in your comment is broken.

Comment: The rules of logic are really quite simple, but IMHO they are rarely presented in a way that is straightforward for the true beginner. In this regard, you may find useful the tutorial on the basic methods of proof (including propositional and predicate logic) that comes with my proof-checking software available free at my homepage: http://www.dcproof.com  (thanks Rob!)

Comment: @DanChristensen From the looks of it, your software is misleading at present and not useful at a basic level.  Every proof in formal logic has to involve well-formed formulas at every step of the proof.  Check the authors who put in the effort to define a proof and be wary of any author who refuses to define what a proof is.  You don't seem to have well-formed formulas at every step in what you call a 'proof' implying that your software doesn't check proofs.  Methods of proof?  But that conversation isn't reasonable without a clear concept of exactly what is and what is not a (formal) proof.

Comment: Maybe try Frege's original "Concept Script" / Begriffsschrift.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood On the contrary, it is probably MORE useful at a basic level (for math undegrads) than any book on mathematical logic that dwells on such philosophical matters. It should be apparent to the user in minutes what a proof is and so on

Comment: @DanChristensen No.  The very first link takes me to something about Russell's paradox.  But, 2 is not well-formed, because parentheses comes as necessary a statement with a binary infix connective to qualify as well-formed.  And every step of a proof has to come as a well-formed formula by definition.  Your example trying to promote your software doesn't do that.  And you expect to get believed on the basis of your say-so?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Line 2 is just '$r\in r \iff \neg r \in r$'. It requires no bracketing in my system where '$\in$' has a high order of precedence than '$\neg$'.

Comment: @DanChristensen You referred to some order of precedence, but you didn't specify your order of precedence in your string.  Nor did you specify how things work since the same symbol appears twice in your string.  And your 'order of precedence' qualifies as a formal substitute for a well-formed formula?  And you believe that it will become clear what a formal proof is within minutes, when we can't even tell what a legal string is and what a legal string is not yet?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood The order of precedence is specified in the Use Reference Guide included in DC Proof 2.0. If you are unfamiliar with this notion, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations at Wiki.

Comment: Can you give an example of a specific point in some text that confuses you? E.g. are you comfortable with the notion of a first-order language and a first-order structure? (In my experience, this is the most common sticking point - and I think this is something that really *does* have a near-prerequisite: it's very recommended to already be familiar with the basic properties of groups and rings, not because these are directly relevant to logic but because they provide examples of types of first-order structures in different languages which are well-motivated outside of logic.)

Comment: The next sticking point is usually around **theories** - do you know what the theory of a structure is, and how to work with *reducts* of structures? (Again, this is a point where the abstract algebra prerequisite above makes sense: "every ring has an underlying group" is a great example of a reduct in mathematics.) And I'm assuming here per your previous comment that you're familiar with the *syntax* of first-order logic. If you're comfortable with all this, then I suspect the sticking points are the proofs and uses of specific theorems. With more information, I can attempt to suggest a text.

Comment: Also, can you explain in what way you find some of these texts "all over the place"? I certainly don't get that feeling from them, but I might be able to suggest a text if I have a better sense of where you're coming from in this regard as well.